# Sequence Space Basis

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the sequence space of all sequences $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots)$ that are *eventually zero*, that is for every $a$ there is a $N$ such that $a_n=0$ for every $n>N$. My question is: how can I describe a basis of this vector space?

Comment: Define a 'standard' basis, show that any such sequence can be written as a finite linear combination of the standard basis vectors. Clearly, these standard basis vectors would be independent.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?  Do you have any "guesses" that might work?

Comment: This is just the vector space of polynomials in disguise (or the other way around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_n=(0,0,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots)$ where 1 is in the $n$th spot. Clearly the $\{e_n\}$ are linearly independent since the $n$th place is zero iff the coefficient of $e_n$ is zero. Furthermore, $\{e_n\}$ clearly span your space since the sequences you're concerned with have only finitely many terms, ie.
$(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_N,0,0,\ldots)=a_0e_0+a_1e_1+\cdots+a_Ne_N$.